# Can I sum integer input from terminal without saving the input as a variable?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a code for digital root of an extremely big number and can't save it as a variable. Is it possible to do without it?

Comment: Yes, C is turing complete, so it theoretically can do anything that a turing machine can do. You should dynamically allocate some buffer and read your input there.

Comment: How big is the "extremely big" number? a few GB? a few TB? PB? EB? ZB? YB? Or large value expressed in short formula like [Graham's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number)?

Comment: If you're going outside of what your `double` can represent then you'll need some kind of "bignum" library to help out. What is the "digital root"?

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks, I will try that! It's around 50 MB.

Comment: @tadman https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root

Comment: Interesting. Hadn't heard of that term before. If it's all integer math, grab a bignum library and you can make numbers of any size you wish, so long as they still fit in memory.

Comment: If the number has at most 50M digits, you can do this without an external library.

Comment: @dbush Oh really? How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking to do is to repeatedly add the digits of a number until you're left with a single digit number, i.e. given 123456, you want 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21 ==> 2 + 1 = 3

For a number with up to 50 million digits, the sum of those digits will be no more than 500 million which is well within the range of a 32-bit `int`.

Start by reading the large number as a string.  Then iterate over each character in the string.  For each character, verify that it's a character digit, i.e. between `'0'` and `'9'`.  Convert that character to the appropriate number, then add that number to the sum.

Once you've done that, you've got the first-level sum stored in an `int`.  Now you can loop through the digits of that number using `x % 10` to get the lowest digit and `x / 10` to shift over the remaining digits.  Once you've exhausted the digits, repeat the process until you're left with a value less than 10.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Sounds like it should work.